# Jenkins Extended Choice Parameter associated to multiple environments variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am using in a Test Jenkins configuration the Choice Parameter in order to select the target environment against the tests are running. 
Like this:
[image]

I use the selected value to pass to the maven test run as selected profile: -Dprofile=${TargetEnv}.

I would like to extend the implementation to make some additional git merge operation before the repository is build and the tests are triggered to run (I don't want to go into detail).

My question is how can I use the "Extended Choice Parameter" Jenkin plugin to have multiple environment variable set when a each choice value.

Example: In case the 'dev' is select then I would like to have two environment variables: targetEnv: qa and lowerEnvBranchName: develop-dev. 
Somebody know how is possible to specify this kind of variables?

Comment: you mean `TargetEnv=dev` is selected then run specific `stage` , right ?

Comment: I meant to have two environments variable set for each possible `TargetEnv`. Ex. When 'dev'  is selected then configure two environments variables: `TargetEnv = dev` and `lowerEnvBranchName = develop`. I need to use these two environments variables in further steps within the Jenkins Job Configuration.